# Multiplication of numbers in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Is there any function in Python which could multiply numbers in a list with each other?

```
input -> A = [1,2,3,4]

output -> B = [1*1, 1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 2*2, 2*3, 2*4, 3*3, 3*4, 4*4]
```

Or can someone help me with creating my own function? I've got over 8000 records and I wouldn't like to do it manually.

So far the only thing I came up with is:

```
for i in list:
    list[i] * list[i+1]
```

But I know that it wouldn't work and I got no idea how to process this data.

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative way using [`combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4]
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> [a * b for a, b in combinations_with_replacement(A, 2)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

```
A = [1,2,3,4]

res = [i*j for i in A for j in A[A.index(i):]]

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
```

Alternative solution:

```
n = len(A)
res = [A[i]*A[j] for i in range(n) for j in range(i, n)]
```